# How can I group 2 images in an Office 365 PowerPoint online presentation?

Tags: images, office-365

I have an Office 365 PowerPoint online presentation. When I try to group 2 images, the `group` option is disabled. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was was able to Group two shapes. Did you select both before right-click and Group?
To select you can either do ctrl+select, or use mouse to 'draw' a box around all the images or shapes on the slide.

[image]